# How execute an onchange event using @Html.InputFor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a view

```
@Html.InputFor(m => m.CurrentAddress.Address.Zip, new { id="currentZip", onchange = "decode_zipcode(currentZip.value,1);" }, disabled:false)
```

And the following Javascript which I want to execute when the value in the above Input changes

```
    var mZipArea = 0;
var vZipCode = document.getElementById('currentZip').value;

function decode_zipcode(vZipCode, vArea) {
    //currentzipCode = vArea;

        if (vZipCode.length == 5) {
            dtdecodeZipCode(vHostUrl, vZipCode, 'return_zipdecode');

    }

}

    function return_zipdecode(vCity, vCounty, vState) {
    if (mZipArea == 1) {
        document.getElementById('currentCity').value = vCity;
        document.getElementById('currentState').value = vState;
        document.getElementById("currentCounty").value = vCounty;
        document.getElementById('currentState').value = "United States";
    }
```

Basically what this does is take the input (zip code) and return the city, state, county, and country.  When I execute the code I do not get any error but the code never executes the javascript.  I am pretty new at MVC and JavaScript so any help with this would be appreciated

**EDIT:  External JS File**

```js
    <script src="/_scripts/dtAddress_v10_r1.js">
   
        function dtaddAddressOption(selectbox, text, value) {
            var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
            optn.text = text;
            optn.value = value;
            selectbox.options.add(optn);

        }

        function dtCountryLookup(vHostUrl,vCountry, oState, vCallBack, vUseAbbr) {

       

            // will return the callback of the state array and proper lables
            //return should look like this
            // myCallBackFunction(vCountyLabel,vCityLabel,vStateLabel,vZipLabel)

            var vCountyLabel = ""
            var vCityLabel = ""
            var vStateLabel = ""
            var vZipLabel = ""
            var vBlank = ""

            if (vUseAbbr == null)
            {
                vUseAbbr = false;
            }




            if (vCountry == 'Canada') {
                // hide the county
                vCountyLabel = "none"
                vCityLabel = "City"
                vStateLabel = "Province"
                vZipLabel = "Postal Code"
                vBlank = "Select Province"
            }

            if (vCountry == 'Mexico') {
                // hide the county

                vCountyLabel = "none"
                vCityLabel = "Division / City / Town"
                vStateLabel = "Province"
                vZipLabel = "Postal Code"
                vBlank = "Select Province"

            }

            if (vCountry == 'United States') {
                // hide the county
                
                vCountyLabel = "County"
                vCityLabel = "City"
                vStateLabel = "State"
                vZipLabel = "Postal Code"
                vBlank = "Select State"

            }

            if (vCountry == '') {
                vCountry = 'United States'
                // hide the county
                vCountyLabel = "County"
                vCityLabel = "City"
                vStateLabel = "State"
                vZipLabel = "Postal Code"
                vBlank = "Select State"


            }

            //get state list
            var oXML = new dtxmlObject
            oXML.createXMLDocument("dealtrace")
            oXML.createXMLRecord("dtrequest")
            oXML.setAttributeValue("action", "901")
            oXML.createXMLRecord("dtrequest_parameter")
            oXML.setAttributeValue("country", vCountry)


            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            //// POST
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            var objHttp = oXML.createHttpObject()
            var vReturn = ""
            objHttp.open("POST", vHostUrl + "/pages/ajax/dt_ajaxservice_open.aspx", 1)
            objHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (objHttp.readyState == 4) {

                    vReturn = objHttp.responseText;

                    oXML.destroyXML()
                    oXML.loadXML(vReturn)
                    oXML.loadXMLRecords("table")
                    var vRecCount = oXML.xmlRecordCount()
                    oState.length = 0
                    dtaddAddressOption(oState, vBlank, "")
                    for (var i = 0; i < vRecCount; i++) {
                        if (oXML.loadXMLRecord(i) == true) {

                            if (vUseAbbr == true) {
                                dtaddAddressOption(oState, oXML.getAttributeValue("stateabbr"), oXML.getAttributeValue("stateabbr"))
                            }
                            else {
                                dtaddAddressOption(oState, oXML.getAttributeValue("statename"), oXML.getAttributeValue("stateabbr"))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    oXML.destroyXML()

                    if (vCallBack != "") {
                        vCallBack = vCallBack + "('" + vCountyLabel + "','" + vCityLabel + "','" + vStateLabel + "','" + vZipLabel + "')"
                        eval(vCallBack);
                    }

                }
            }
            objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
            objHttp.send(oXML.getXML())

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            /// END POST
            /////////////////////////////////////////

//            // SUBMIT TO SERVER
//            var objHttp = oXML.createHttpObject()
//            var b
//            var vReturn = ""
//            
//            b = objHttp.open("POST", vHostUrl + "/pages/ajax/dt_ajaxservice_open.aspx", 0)
//            b = objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
//            b = objHttp.send(oXML.getXML())

//            vReturn = objHttp.responseText;
//            oXML.loadXML(vReturn)
//            oXML.loadXMLRecords("table")
//            var vRecCount = oXML.xmlRecordCount()
//            oState.length = 0
//            dtaddAddressOption(oState, vBlank, "")
//            for (var i = 0; i < vRecCount; i++) {
//                if (oXML.loadXMLRecord(i) == true) {
//                    dtaddAddressOption(oState, oXML.getAttributeValue("statename"), oXML.getAttributeValue("stateabbr"))
//                }
//            }
//            oXML.destroyXML()

//            if (vCallBack != "") {
//                vCallBack = vCallBack + "('" + vCountyLabel + "','" + vCityLabel + "','" + vStateLabel + "','" + vZipLabel + "')"
//                eval(vCallBack);
//            }

        }




        function dtdecodeZipCode(vHostUrl, vZipCode, vCallBack) {



            // will return the callback of the state array and proper lables
            //return should look like this
            // myCallBackFunction(vCounty,vCity,vState)
            var vCounty
            var vCity
            var vState



            if (vZipCode.length == 5) {
                var oXML = new dtxmlObject
                oXML.createXMLDocument("dealtrace")
                oXML.createXMLRecord("dtrequest")
                oXML.setAttributeValue("action", "101")
                oXML.createXMLRecord("dtrequest_parameter")
                oXML.setAttributeValue("zipcode", vZipCode)


                ///////////////////////////////////////////
                //// POST
                //////////////////////////////////////////
                var objHttp = oXML.createHttpObject()
                var vReturn = ""
                objHttp.open("POST", vHostUrl + "/pages/ajax/dt_ajaxservice_open.aspx", 1)
                objHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (objHttp.readyState == 4) {

                        vReturn = objHttp.responseText;

                        oXML.destroyXML()
                        oXML.loadXML(vReturn)
                        oXML.loadXMLRecords("table")
                        if (oXML.loadXMLRecord(0) == true) {
                            vCity = oXML.getAttributeValue("city").replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "");
                            vCounty = oXML.getAttributeValue("county").replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "");
                            vState = oXML.getAttributeValue("state").replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "");
                        }
                        oXML.destroyXML()

                        if (vCallBack != "") {
                            vCallBack = vCallBack + "('" + vCity + "','" + vCounty + "','" + vState + "')"
                            eval(vCallBack);
                        }
                    }
                }
                objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                objHttp.send(oXML.getXML())

                //////////////////////////////////////////
                /// END POST
                /////////////////////////////////////////

                //                // SUBMIT TO SERVER
                //                var objHttp = oXML.createHttpObject()
                //                var b
                //                var vReturn = ""

                //                b = objHttp.open("POST",  vHostUrl + "/pages/ajax/dt_ajaxservice_open.aspx", 0)
                //                b = objHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                //                b = objHttp.send(oXML.getXML())
                //                vReturn = objHttp.responseText;
                //                oXML.loadXML(vReturn)
                //                oXML.loadXMLRecords("table")
                //                if (oXML.loadXMLRecord(0) == true) {
                //                    vCity = oXML.getAttributeValue("city").replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "");
                //                    vCounty = oXML.getAttributeValue("county").replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "");
                //                    vState = oXML.getAttributeValue("state").replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "");
                //                }
                //                oXML.destroyXML()
            } else {

                            if (vCallBack != "") {
                                vCallBack = vCallBack + "('" + vCity + "','" + vCounty + "','" + vState + "')"
                                eval(vCallBack);
                            }


            }


        }
    
</script>
```

Comment: `.InputFor()` is that your own extension? What does your rendered html look like?

Comment: Yes that is our extension it is the same as a TextBoxFor just named differently.  I will get you the rendered html asap

Comment: When I look at the rendered HTML our external js file that is associated with it.  I edited the post to include the external js file

Comment: 1) What kind of html element does `.InputFor()` render? 2) Does that element type support the `onchange` event? 3) Are your scripts loading properly?

Comment: I just ran firebug upon executing the code and it is saying "vZipCode is undefined" so I am thinking that my declaration of the variable for vZipCode is incorrect.  That is the only error it is throwing (so far)

Comment: Oh sorry I missed one question as well.  It is a basic textbox so I believe that does support the onchange event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Html.TextBox I tried this and it works.

```
@Html.TextBox("txtTime" , value : null , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange="alert(value);"})
```